# Grunt build is not working after NPM Update and Clean

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, gruntjs, bower

I have my website on AngularJs and it was working just fine before we updated the NPM clean. Whenever we tried to build the project with 'Grunt Build' it gets stuck after processing the images part.

> Reinstalled NPM previous version
>
> Resetup complete environment
>
> Deleted cache and everything
>
> ```
> $ grunt build -v
> Initializing
> Command-line options: --verbose, --gruntfile=C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\Gruntfile.js
>
> Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK
>
> Registering Gruntfile tasks.
> =============================================================================
> ```

```
Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.

Registering "grunt-autoprefixer" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\package.json...OK
Loading "autoprefixer.js" tasks...OK
+ autoprefixer

Registering "grunt-filerev-replace" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-filerev-replace\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-filerev-replace\package.json...OK
Loading "filerev_replace.js" tasks...OK
+ filerev_replace

Registering "grunt-concurrent" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-concurrent\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-concurrent\package.json...OK
Loading "concurrent.js" tasks...OK
+ concurrent

Registering "grunt-contrib-clean" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-clean\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-clean\package.json...OK
Loading "clean.js" tasks...OK
+ clean

Registering "grunt-contrib-concat" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-concat\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-concat\package.json...OK
Loading "concat.js" tasks...OK
+ concat

Registering "grunt-contrib-connect" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-connect\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-connect\package.json...OK
Loading "connect.js" tasks...OK
+ connect

Registering "grunt-contrib-copy" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-copy\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-copy\package.json...OK
Loading "copy.js" tasks...OK
+ copy

Registering "grunt-contrib-cssmin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-cssmin\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-cssmin\package.json...OK
Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...OK
+ cssmin

Registering "grunt-contrib-htmlmin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-htmlmin\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-htmlmin\package.json...OK
Loading "htmlmin.js" tasks...OK
+ htmlmin

Registering "grunt-contrib-imagemin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\package.json...OK
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...OK
+ imagemin

Registering "grunt-contrib-jshint" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\package.json...OK
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...OK
+ jshint

Registering "grunt-contrib-uglify" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-uglify\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-uglify\package.json...OK
Loading "uglify.js" tasks...OK
+ uglify

Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\package.json...OK
Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch

Registering "grunt-filerev" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-filerev\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-filerev\package.json...OK
Loading "filerev.js" tasks...OK
+ filerev

Registering "grunt-google-cdn" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\package.json...OK
Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...OK
+ cdnify

Registering "grunt-newer" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-newer\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-newer\package.json...OK
Loading "newer.js" tasks...OK
+ any-newer, newer, newer-clean, newer-postrun

Registering "grunt-ng-annotate" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-ng-annotate\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-ng-annotate\package.json...OK
Loading "ng-annotate.js" tasks...OK
+ ngAnnotate

Registering "grunt-svgmin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-svgmin\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-svgmin\package.json...OK
Loading "svgmin.js" tasks...OK
+ svgmin

Registering "grunt-usemin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-usemin\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-usemin\package.json...OK
Loading "usemin.js" tasks...OK
+ usemin, useminPrepare

Registering "grunt-wiredep" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-wiredep\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\YouStable\Documents\newyst\node_modules\grunt-wiredep\package.json...OK
Loading "wiredep.js" tasks...OK
+ wiredep
Initializing config...OK
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ build, default, serve, server, test

Running tasks: svgmin

Running "svgmin" task

Running "svgmin:dist" (svgmin) task
Verifying property svgmin.dist exists in config...OK
Files: app/images/1-high.svg -> dist/images/1-high.svg
Files: app/images/9-high.svg -> dist/images/9-high.svg
Files: app/images/dreamhost.svg -> dist/images/dreamhost.svg
Files: app/images/icons/cd-arrow.svg -> dist/images/icons/cd-arrow.svg
Files: app/images/icons/cloud.svg -> dist/images/icons/cloud.svg
Files: app/images/icons/contract.svg -> dist/images/icons/contract.svg
Files: app/images/icons/curriculum.svg -> dist/images/icons/curriculum.svg
Files: app/images/icons/http.svg -> dist/images/icons/http.svg
Files: app/images/icons/piggy-bank.svg -> dist/images/icons/piggy-bank.svg
Files: app/images/icons/sms_interact.svg -> dist/images/icons/sms_interact.svg
Files: app/images/icons/speaker.svg -> dist/images/icons/speaker.svg
Files: app/images/icons/website.svg -> dist/images/icons/website.svg
Files: app/images/lowa.svg -> dist/images/lowa.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/boy.svg -> dist/images/svgs/boy.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/call.svg -> dist/images/svgs/call.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/cancel.svg -> dist/images/svgs/cancel.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/chat.svg -> dist/images/svgs/chat.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/chat1.svg -> dist/images/svgs/chat1.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/check.svg -> dist/images/svgs/check.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/Digital_Marketing_Image.svg -> dist/images/svgs/Digital_Marketing_Image.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/drupal.svg -> dist/images/svgs/drupal.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/email.svg -> dist/images/svgs/email.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/ink.svg -> dist/images/svgs/ink.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/joomla.svg -> dist/images/svgs/joomla.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/like.svg -> dist/images/svgs/like.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/magento.svg -> dist/images/svgs/magento.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/man.svg -> dist/images/svgs/man.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/phone-call.svg -> dist/images/svgs/phone-call.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/picture.svg -> dist/images/svgs/picture.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/shopping-cart.svg -> dist/images/svgs/shopping-cart.svg
Files: app/images/svgs/wordpress.svg -> dist/images/svgs/wordpress.svg
Options: (none)
Reading app/images/1-high.svg...OK
√ app/images/1-high.svg (saved 7 B 0%)
Writing dist/images/1-high.svg...OK
Reading app/images/9-high.svg...OK
√ app/images/9-high.svg (saved 76.48 kB 25%)
Writing dist/images/9-high.svg...OK
Reading app/images/dreamhost.svg...OK
√ app/images/dreamhost.svg (saved 147 B 6%)
Writing dist/images/dreamhost.svg...OK
Reading app/images/icons/cd-arrow.svg...OK
√ app/images/icons/cd-arrow.svg (saved 156 B 42%)
Writing dist/images/icons/cd-arrow.svg...OK
Reading app/images/icons/cloud.svg...OK
√ app/images/icons/cloud.svg (saved 2.97 kB 47%)
Writing dist/images/icons/cloud.svg...OK
Reading app/images/icons/contract.svg...OK
√ app/images/icons/contract.svg (saved 900 B 35%)
Writing dist/images/icons/contract.svg...OK
Reading app/images/icons/curriculum.svg...OK
√ app/images/icons/curriculum.svg (saved 887 B 27%)
Writing dist/images/icons/curriculum.svg...OK
Reading app/images/icons/http.svg...OK
√ app/images/icons/http.svg (saved 1.18 kB 29%)
Writing dist/images/icons/http.svg...OK
Reading app/images/icons/piggy-bank.svg...OK
√ app/images/icons/piggy-bank.svg (saved 1.07 kB 17%)
Writing dist/images/icons/piggy-bank.svg...OK
Reading app/images/icons/sms_interact.svg...OK
√ app/images/icons/sms_interact.svg (saved 9.31 kB 55%)
Writing dist/images/icons/sms_interact.svg...OK
Reading app/images/icons/speaker.svg...OK
√ app/images/icons/speaker.svg (saved 1.04 kB 29%)
Writing dist/images/icons/speaker.svg...OK
Reading app/images/icons/website.svg...OK
√ app/images/icons/website.svg (saved 1.3 kB 27%)
Writing dist/images/icons/website.svg...OK
Reading app/images/lowa.svg...OK
√ app/images/lowa.svg (saved 47.01 kB 27%)
Writing dist/images/lowa.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/boy.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/boy.svg (saved 1.47 kB 22%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/boy.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/call.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/call.svg (saved 614 B 22%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/call.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/cancel.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/cancel.svg (saved 233 B 50%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/cancel.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/chat.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/chat.svg (saved 286 B 19%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/chat.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/chat1.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/chat1.svg (saved 283 B 19%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/chat1.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/check.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/check.svg (saved 182 B 50%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/check.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/Digital_Marketing_Image.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/Digital_Marketing_Image.svg (saved 24.02 kB 23%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/Digital_Marketing_Image.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/drupal.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/drupal.svg (saved 22.07 kB 88%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/drupal.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/email.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/email.svg (saved 1.24 kB 22%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/email.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/ink.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/ink.svg (saved 3.31 kB 41%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/ink.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/joomla.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/joomla.svg (saved 1.29 kB 44%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/joomla.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/like.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/like.svg (saved 382 B 23%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/like.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/magento.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/magento.svg (saved 435 B 40%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/magento.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/man.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/man.svg (saved 1.5 kB 23%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/man.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/phone-call.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/phone-call.svg (saved 741 B 26%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/phone-call.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/picture.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/picture.svg (saved 450 B 24%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/picture.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/shopping-cart.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/shopping-cart.svg (saved 663 B 39%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/shopping-cart.svg...OK
Reading app/images/svgs/wordpress.svg...OK
√ app/images/svgs/wordpress.svg (saved 715 B 35%)
Writing dist/images/svgs/wordpress.svg...OK
Total saved: 202.33 kB

Done.
```

Execution Time (2019-03-26 10:12:18 UTC+5:30)
    loading tasks  13ms  █ 1%
    svgmin:dist      2s  ███████████████████████████████████████████████ 99%
    Total 2s

Its still working fine on other device with old setup but new setup doesn't work at all. Please check and review.

Comment: Since you did an `npm clean` it removed all modules that were not present in the **package.json** file, but might being used in the application. please compare the old node_mouldes folder with the new one and add the missing modules.

Comment: @Ayush I tried to reinstall everything but didn't work and if there is something then it should process some error as well.

Answer (score 0):

What is the node version are you using? There might be compatibility issues.

You haven't pasted the what error you got.! So, will give you the general troubleshooting of the issue.

For troubleshooting whenever you are facing kind of wired issue. Just go ahead and clean the cache by using `npm cache clean`.

Comment: I already cleared the cache and there is no error just stuck without any error